# Is my definition correct? How do I prove the finite union of elements of $\mathscr U$ lie in $\mathscr U$?

Tags: general-topology

Definition of basis for a topology on $X$ given in the Foundation of Topology By Patty given by

> Let $(X,\mathscr T)$ be a topological space. A basis for $\mathscr T$
>   is a subcollection $\mathscr B$ of $\mathscr T$ with the property that
>   if $U\in \mathscr T$ then $U=\emptyset$ or there is a subcollection
>   $\mathscr B'$ such that $U=\bigcup \{B:B\in \mathscr B'\}$

**How do I write the definition of basis for the family of closed sets?**

**My attempt:-**

> Let $(X,\mathscr U)$ be a family of closed sets(closed sets of topology on $X$). A basis for $\mathscr
>  U$ is a subcollection $\mathscr D$ of $\mathscr U$ with the property
>   that if $D\in \mathscr U$ then $D=X$ or there is a subcollection
>   $\mathscr D'$ such that $D=\bigcap \{D:D\in \mathscr D'\}$

**am I correct?**

My next aim is to prove the following Result. This result I have seen in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266818/base-topology-with-closed-intervals) given by Brian M Scott.

> A family $\mathscr X\subseteq\wp(X)$ is a *base for the closed sets*
>   of topology on $X$ iff
>
> - $\bigcap_{D\in \mathscr X} D=\varnothing$, and
> - if $D_0,D_1\in\mathscr X$ and $x\notin D_0\cup D_1$, then there is a $D_2\in\mathscr X$ such that $x\notin D_2\supseteq D_0\cup D_1$.

**My attempt for the proof:-**

Suppose  A family $\mathscr X\subseteq\wp(X)$ is a *base for the closed sets*
of topology on $X.$

**claim 1:- $\bigcap_{D\in \mathscr X} D=\varnothing$**

$\varnothing \in \mathscr U$. so by the definition of basis there is a subcollection $\mathscr X'$: $\varnothing=\bigcap \{C:C\in \mathscr X'\}$. Hence,$\bigcap_{D\in \mathscr X} D=\varnothing.$

**Claim 2:-if $D_0,D_1\in\mathscr X$ and $x\notin D_0\cup D_1$, then there is a $D_2\in\mathscr X$ such that $x\notin D_2\supseteq D_0\cup D_1$**

if $D_0,D_1\in\mathscr X \implies D_0,D_1\in \mathscr U \implies D_0 \cup D_1 \in \mathscr U \implies \exists \mathscr X'':D_0 \cup D_1 =\bigcap \{C:C\in \mathscr X''\}. $ If $x\notin D_0 \cup D_1 \implies \exists C'\in \mathscr X'': x \notin C'.$

Conversely suppose family of subsets $\mathscr X$ satisfies the following

I. $\bigcap_{D\in \mathscr X} D=\varnothing$, and

II. if $D_0,D_1\in\mathscr X$ and $x\notin D_0\cup D_1$, then there is a $D_2\in\mathscr X$ such that $x\notin D_2\supseteq D_0\cup D_1$.

**Claim:-A family $\mathscr X\subseteq\wp(X)$ is a *base for the closed sets*
 of topology on $X$**. Let $\mathscr
 U$ is a subcollection of $\wp(X)$ consisting of $X$ and those sets are the intersection of members of $\mathscr X$. Our aim is to prove $\mathscr U$ is topology of closed sets on $x$.

(a)$X\in \mathscr U(\because \text{ by the definition of} \mathscr U$). $\emptyset \in \mathscr U (\because \text{ by the definition of} \mathscr U $ and (I)).

(b)Arbitrary intersection of closed set lie in the $\mathscr U$ immediately.

**(c)How do I prove the finite union of elements of $\mathscr U$ lie in $\mathscr U$?**

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $\mathscr U$.

Comment: Sir, I have corrected the definition of $\mathscr U$. Let $\mathscr
 U$ is a subcollection of $\wp(X)$ consisting of $X$ and those sets are the intersection of members of $\mathscr X$

Comment: I don't know what any of this means (some stuff, yes, but most stuff no), although I just want to say, that `\mathscr` font is so pretty. Thank you for using it so I could see. $(+1)$ $\color{orange}{\bigstar}$ xD

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand :(

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr D$ be the basis for closed sets that we are working with.

If $A\cup B$, then there is nothing to prove. So let us assume that $X\setminus (A\cup B)\ne\emptyset$.

Then we have $A=\bigcap \mathscr D'_0$, $B=\bigcap \mathscr D'_1$ for some $\mathscr D'_{0,1}\subseteq\mathscr D$.

Let us now take the set
$$S=\{(x,D_0,D_1,D_2); D_2\in\mathscr D, x\in X, x\notin D_2; D_0\cup D_1\subseteq D_2, D_0\in\mathscr D'_0, D_1\in\mathscr D'_1\}.$$
We want to show that
$$A\cup B=\bigcap \{D_2; (x,D_0,D_1,D_2)\in S\text{ for some }x, D_0, D_1\}=:C.$$

Since for every $D_2$ as above we have $D_2\supseteq D_0 \supseteq A$, we get $C\supseteq A$. By the same reasoning we have $C\supseteq B$ and, consequently, $C\supseteq A\cup B$.

It remains to show that $C\subseteq A\cup B$. Assume that, on the contrary, there exists $x\in C$ such that $x\notin A\cup B$. But since $x\notin A\cup B$ we have $x\notin D_0$ and $x\notin D_1$ for some $D_0\in\mathscr D'_0$, $D_1\in\mathscr D'_1$. Therefore there exists $D_2\in\mathscr D$ such that $x\notin D_2$ and $D_0\cup D_1\subseteq D_2$. But then $(x,D_0,D_1,D_2)\in S$, and from $x\notin D_2$ we get $x\notin C$.