# Show that $\{Z(p):p\in \mathscr P\}$ is a basis for the closed sets of some topology (Called the Zariski topology) on $\mathbb R^n$.

Tags: general-topology, zariski-topology

**Let $n\in \mathbb N$, and let $\mathscr P$ denote the collection of all polynomials in $n$ variables. For $p\in \mathscr P$, let $Z(p)=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0\}$.
Show that $\{Z(p):p\in \mathscr P\}$ is a basis for the closed sets of some topology (Called the [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology)) on $\mathbb R^n$.**

My attempt:-

I used the result for [Basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071767/is-my-definition-correct-how-do-i-prove-the-finite-union-of-elements-of-maths)  for the closed sets of topology on X.

(I)  We need to prove that $\bigcap_{p\in \mathscr P}Z(p)=\emptyset.$ $Z(p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=1)=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0\}=\emptyset$. Which implies $\bigcap_{p\in \mathscr P}Z(p) \subset Z(p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=1)=\emptyset \implies \bigcap_{p\in \mathscr P}Z(p)=\emptyset.$

(II) if $Z(p_0),Z(p_1)\in\mathscr X$ and $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \notin Z(p_0)\cup Z(p_1)$, then there is a $Z(p_2)\in\mathscr X$ such that $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \notin Z(p_2)\supseteq Z(p_0)\cup Z(p_1)$.

$(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \notin Z(p_0)\cup Z(p_1)\implies p_0(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\neq0$ and $p_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\neq 0.$ We can choose $p_2=p_0 p_1$ such that $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\notin Z(p_2)$. We know that $Z(p_0)\cup Z(p_1) \subset Z(p_2)$.

Have I done the proof correctly?

Comment: Define:  Z(p = 1).

Comment: $Z(p)=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0\}$

Comment: When we substitute $p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=1$ we get $Z(p=1)$. which is an empty set.

Comment: If I define like this, is my proof correct?

Comment: No, Z is defined for polynomials, it is not defined for statements like p = 1.  Thus Z(p = 1) is meaningless.

Comment: I meant constant polynomial.

Comment: Z(p) where p = 1 or Z(1) isn't geeky.

Comment: yes. You were talking about the proof of the first part. right?

Answer (score 0):

$Z(p) \cup Z(q) = Z(pq)$.
Let 1 be the polynomial of $n$ variables with constant value 1.
$Z(1)$ is empty.

Comment: what about the second property?

Comment: The first line proves it.

Comment: @Mathgeek the product of two polynomials is a polynomial. So define $p_2=p_1 p_2$ in your proof attempt.

Comment: That is how I defined @HennoBrandsma. I defined $p_2=p_1p_0$.

Comment: In the second part of the proof.

Comment: But you need that $Z(p_2) =Z(p_0) \cup Z(p_1)$, because we need $x \notin Z(p_0) \cup Z(p_1)$ and that now follows. @Mathgeek Or prove separately that $x \notin Z(p_2)$.

Comment: What do you mean? Is my proof correct? How do I prove separately that $x\notin Z(p_2)$?

Answer (score 0):

The set of $\{Z(I): I \subseteq \mathcal{P}\}$, where $Z(I)=\bigcap_{p \in I} Z(p)$ is in fact the **whole** topology, not just a closed base for it, as I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3000868/4280).
The basis fact immediately follows, by the definition of a closed base (you can write all closed sets as intersection of base elements).

Comment: No, We want to prove $\{Z(p_1),Z(p_2),...,Z(p_n),....\}$ is a basic set.

Comment: @Mathgeek if $C$ is closed, then $C = Z(I)= \bigcap \{Z(p): p \in I\}$. BTW, don’t think the base is countable, it is not, though you seem to suggest so.