# Is my result and proof correct?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathscr T)$ be a topological space. If $\mathscr B=\{B_{\alpha}:\alpha \in \Lambda\}$ is a collection of closed sets that forms a [base for the closed subsets of $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071884/show-that-zpp-in-mathscr-p-is-a-basis-for-the-closed-sets-of-some-topo). Will $\mathscr D=\{B^c:B\in \mathscr B\}$ form a base for $\mathscr T$?

My Attempt.
Claim:-$\mathscr D=\{B^c:B\in \mathscr B\}$ forms a basis for $\mathscr T$

(1) $\bigcup_{B\in \mathscr B}B^c=(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha)^c=\emptyset^c=X$

(2)$B_1^c,B_2^c \in \mathscr D$ and $x\in B_1^c \cap B_2^c\implies x\in (B_1 \cup B_2)^c $. Then there is $B_3\in \mathscr B: x\notin B_3\supseteq B_1 \cup B_2$. Taking the complement on Both sides. We get $x\in B_3^c\subseteq B_1^c \cap B_2^c$. Hence, $\mathscr D$ forms a basis for $\mathscr T$.

Is my result and proof correct?

Comment: No.  You omitted a requirement of a topological space,

Comment: can you please explain? what did I miss?

Comment: Please for the next time, add what the question is about on the title, so that people can know beforehand whether they will be able to help or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology is given, so note that in a base for the closed sets all $\mathcal{T}$-closed sets are intersection of subfamilies of $\mathcal{B}$, so by de Morgan all $\mathcal{T}$-open sets are unions of their complements, and $\{B^\complement: B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ thus forms a base *for $\mathcal{T}$*.

You are checking the general precondition for forming a possible base in general, not for this topology specifically.